# how u-boot can detect a script inside a USB stick whatever the partition

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

**TLDR:** My question is how to do a more generic script in the case of multiple partitions in a USB stick where one of them contains a boot.scr file (not necessarily the first partition).

In `U-boot` prompt, I have environment variables which basically detect if there is a `boot.scr` script inside first partition of my usb stick. If so it should run it. This script is supposed to launch an initramfs.

These new environment variables are added using `CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS` macro in `u-boot` sources [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75547754/yocto-add-custom-uboot-environment-variables)

```sh
"usb_bootscript=load usb 0:1 ${scriptaddr} ${bsp_script}\0" \
"usb_bootcmd=usb start ; if run usb_bootscript; then source ${scriptaddr}; else usb stop; fi;\0" \
"bsp_bootcmd=echo Running BSP bootcmd ...; " \
    "run usb_bootcmd " \
    "mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then " \
       "if run loadbootscript; then " \
           "run bootscript; " \
       "else " \
           "if run loadimage; then " \
               "run mmcboot; " \
           "else run netboot; " \
           "fi; " \
       "fi; " \
   "fi;"
```

This code work in the current state.

Here `usb_bootscript` check inside `usb 0:1`. My question is how to do a more generic script in the case of multiple partitions in USB stick. With one of them contains a boot.scr file (not necessarily the first partition)

Comment: (I have edited the original code to show the structure of the `if/then/else`s but have left in redundant `;` chars, as that is what the O.P. had included). Good luck to all.

Comment: you seem to be relying on a command name `run`. My linux doesn't have that. Please edit your question to provide more context about how/"where" this is being run. Does it work in it's current state? If so, the you are only interested in `... more generic ... whereever the boot.scr...` ? Does this environment (with a `run` command) have a `for` or `while` loop available OR a *nix type `find` command? It would be better if you update your question rather than reply in comments. Leave a comment that you have updated your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter at the same time you may also enable syntax highlighting and do other simple tweaks.

Comment: @Dandriy : Cool that looks great. I"ll have to look in formatting help to see how to do that. ALSO, I realize now that my statements abouve about the `;` chars being redundant is not correct. This is `u-boot` code and they are required as is having `then` on a line below the `if` .... AND the continuation chars at the end of each line. I may take time to loo at `u-boot` "language" to see if it offers a `for` loop to help resolve this prroblem. Good luck to all

Comment: nice hint @shellter

Comment: I tried, but the u-boot environment is too to deep to research this without reading a book (IMHO /-;) . Going to add a bounty as it is an interesting problem, and hopefully @sawdust willl take a look it. I recommend that you move your `My question is...` at the bottom to the top o the question and precdede it with `TLDR:`. Good luck.