# How to modify default empty string on U-Boot to stop Autoboot in Yocto

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, u-boot, microchip

I am using the SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK-SD evaluation kit and I would like to make some changes to U-Boot, in particular the Autoboot settings. I am able to load a kernel image using Yocto, and by default when U-Boot loads, it asks user to "Hit any key to STOP autoboot". I'd like for this empty string to be a custom string (e.g "abort").

Following other posts, I can do this by modifying the sama5d27_som1_ek_mmc_defconfig, but I don't see a variable to modify.

Also, I've tried changing the string by using "menuconfig" and I'm able set the string; and settings get saved in a ".config" file, but I don't think I could modify this file as it is an output.

Which file should I be modifying?

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks.

Gil

Comment: "*Which file should I be modifying?*" - Possibly none. You would first have to use the menuconfig system to properly configure U-Boot.  Study [doc/README.autoboot](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/v2023.10/source/doc/README.autoboot). For the mentioned environment variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75547754/yocto-add-custom-uboot-environment-variables/75551399#75551399.

Comment: I'm able to launch u-boot menuconfig by running "bitbake u-boot -c devshell" -> make menuconfig. I am able to get into "Boot Options -> Autoboot Options" and modify the corresponding variables, Delay and Stop autbooting via specific input key/string. I verified these changes are made in the ".config" file (e.g CONFIG_BOOTDELAY=20, CONFIG_AUTOBOOT_STOP_STR="stop"). I then run bitbake core-image-minimal; but I don't see the mods on my SAMA5D27 target board. Is this process correct? Are there any other files I have to modify? Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: "*but I don't see the mods ...*" - So how did you verify that you booted the new binary?  How did you verify that you installed the new binary? How did you verify that you built a new binary?

Answer (score -1):

Try configure `CONFIG_BOOTDELAY`[[1]](https://elixir.bootlin.com/u-boot/v2023.10/source/configs/sama5d27_som1_ek_mmc_defconfig#L35) with value -2.

What version of u-boot are you using?

Comment: I am using "U-Boot 2023.07-.02-linux4microchip-2023.10-rc3". It still doesn't work when I make the assignment. Also, in the sama5d27_som1_ek_mmc_defconfig file, I don't see the option to change the STOP_STRING; only CONFIG_BOOTDELAY. Do I have have to make my own defconfig and add this variable to it? Thanks